# How do I store the destination filepath i copied using shutil into a variable

Tags: python, operating-system, shutil

The problem is that I would like to copy the file uploaded to a new folder called 'video store', then the name of the file that has just been copied to 'video store' is stored in a variable to be used to change the file name to the random Id number assigned to it.

```
def loadVideo():
     global filePath
     filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename() #original filepath
 
randomId = random.randint(1,1000000) 
 
#upload video file 
shutil.copy(filePath, "video store") #file is copied to new path
newPath = "/video store/[found file name]" #this is the where the filename would be found and stored in the variable 'newpath'
os.rename(newPath, randomId) #renames the file copied to the random ID
messagebox.showinfo("", "Upload successful!")
```

Comment: In summary, I need to rename the file that i copied to the new directory to 'randomId'

Comment: Is it intentionally that the folder name is writte differently in both occurences (`video store` vs `videostore`)?

Comment: sorry, I didnt notice that, no the folder name should be written as 'video store' both times